# ISSUE with ColdFusion TRANSACTION and Data Concurrency

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am creating and assigning a value in a variable at the top of the function. But somehow the value gets replaced with other user's table record. This happened when two users doing transaction at same time with different records. Also it is happening only once in a while.
I have mentioned the issue in comments in below code.

```
<cffunction name="functionname" output="true"> 
<cfargument name="formData"> 
<cftransaction action="begin"> 
    <cftry>
        <cfquery name="getDoc_no" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
            SELECT CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY'),WORK_REQ_SEQ.NEXTVAL)  as NEXT_NO FROM DUAL
        </cfquery>  
        <cfset doc_no_seq=getDoc_no.NEXT_NO> <!---creating variable doc_no_seq --->

        <cfquery name="getWo_no" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
            SELECT  WORK_ORDER_SEQ.nextval  as NEXT_NO FROM DUAL
        </cfquery>  
        <cfset Trns_seq=getWo_no.NEXT_NO>  <!--- creating variable Trns_seq --->

        <cfquery name="insert1" datasource="#variables.dsn#">   
            INSERT into  WORK_ORDER
            (
                DOC_NO, 
                TRANS_ID 
            ) 
            Values 
            (
                <cfqueryparam value="#doc_no_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">, <!--- Inserted CORRECT doc_no_seq value  --->
                <cfqueryparam value="#Trns_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> <!--- Inserted CORRECT Trns_seq value  --->
            )   
        </cfquery>
        <cfif isdefined("IdnoRes") and IdnoRes gt 0>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#IdnoRes#" index="q">
                <cfif trim(Evaluate("rsc_grp_id_#q#")) is not "" and  trim(Evaluate("qty_#q#")) is not "">
                    <cfquery name="insert2" datasource="#variables.dsn#">       
                        INSERT into REQ_RESOURCE_DTLS
                        (
                            DOC_NO        , 
                            TRANS_ID       
                        )
                        Values 
                        (
                            <cfqueryparam value="#doc_no_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">, <!--- Inserted WRONG doc_no_seq value  --->
                            <cfqueryparam value="#Trns_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> <!--- Inserted WRONG Trns_seq value  --->
                        )
                    </cfquery>      
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif> 
        <cfif isdefined("Idnojob") and Idnojob gt 0>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#Idnojob#" index="q">
                <cfif trim(Evaluate("frm_des_#q#")) is not "" and  trim(Evaluate("to_des_#q#")) is not "">
                    <cfquery name="insert3" datasource="#variables.dsn#">       
                        INSERT into JOB_SEQ_DTLS
                        (
                            DOC_NO        , 
                            TRANS_ID       
                        )
                        Values 
                        (
                            <cfqueryparam value="#doc_no_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">, <!--- Inserted WRONG doc_no_seq value  --->
                            <cfqueryparam value="#Trns_seq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">  <!--- Inserted WRONG Trns_seq value  --->
                        )
                    </cfquery>      
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>     

        <cftransaction action="commit" />
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cftransaction action="rollback" />          
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cftransaction> 

<cfreturn 1>
```

Comment: Keep all your variables, including query names, local to the function.  You can use the local scope or the keyword `var` to do this.

Comment: To clarify, it sounds like you are experiencing race conditions. Most likely you are storing the component in a shared scope, which means any variables declared inside the function that are *not* properly localized end up in the `variables` scope, which is accessible to multiple threads, and subject to race conditions. The solution is to ensure *all* function local variables are localized with either `local` or `var`. That includes ALL variables local to the function - loop indexes, query names - all variables.

Comment: Also 1) No need to use evaluate(). Most scopes are structures, so use structure notation, ie `theScopeName["variableName"& index]` 2) Scope all variables, ie Use `arguments.variableName` instead of just `variableName` and 3) IsDefined() sometimes has an overly broad reach. It is preferable to use structKeyExists() instead.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you very much. Let me try this.

Comment: @Leigh Thank you very much